# How to play video using QPython

Tags: android, media, qpython

I am new to QPython and all I need to do is play a video (stored on the Android Tablet), and wait until the video finish playing.

I found the Androidhelper library commands mediaPlay and mediaIsPlaying functions, but I would not know where to start to use these functions.

Sorry, I did say I am new, so I would appreciate the basics, like how to get the source file directory, etc., a one line example would be fine.

Also if there is a better library to do this, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not API for Qpython, but there is a a8player.py in scripts after you having installed the Qpython, which maybe show how to call a player app's API.

BTW: you could post the requiement in official's facebook page. The dev team is very nice.